# JQuery queue and dequeue

Tags: jquery

I have multiple jquery ajax calls that are somewhat interdependent. Both are fired on page load at different times (with `getData` being called before `showData` and `showData` is dependent on `getData` being called first).

On some clients, the `showData` runs first before `getData`.

1. How do I recreate this error as we don't see that happening everywhere. It appears that this depends on the load on the server but we are unable to confirm that.
2. To fix it, I understand I can use Jquery's `queue` and `dequeue`. However, in certian scenarios, I need to run this outside of the queueing infrastructure. For example, my `getData` looks like this:

   ```
   function getData() {

      $.ajax(//options)

   }

   function showData() {

      $.ajax(//options)

   }
   ```

Sometimes, I need both of them to be executed (with `getData` being called first), but in certain scenarios, they are independent of each other with `getData` being called without ever calling `showData`.

If I queue them up, can I still call them independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) types available in jQuery 1.5+ rather than a queue:

```
function getData() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

function showData() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}

var gd = getData();

if (showDataNeeded) {
    // only call showData() when getData() has finished
    gd.done(showData);
}
```

Comment: I don't see you using `$.Defferred()` in your code. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dusty sorry - it's implicit - the `$.ajax()` call returns a deferred object.  I've rephrased it.

Comment: @Dust it's just something I put in to represent that you said sometimes you don't want to do `showData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just attach `showData` to `getData`'s on success callback like this:

```
function getData(){
$.ajax({
  url: "/your.url",
  success: showData
});
}

function showData(){
  // foo bar here
}
```

This also deals with the fact that you might not want to call `showData` **unless** `getData` succeeds.